# Convert JSON "/Date(1404860400000)/" to javascript date

Tags: c#, javascript, json, wcf, date

so I am currently creating a webpage that uses data from an Oracle database. I am retrieving a list of data from the database and displaying it on the webpage. The problem is that when retrieving the data, the dates which are located in the list come back as JSON dates.

So whenever I retrieve a date from the database using JSON and try to display it on my webpage, its shown in this format: "/Date(1404860400000)/"

How can I convert this into a date like "dd-mm-yy":"21-AUG-14"?

My current code is like so:

JavaScript - For formatting the data and displaying in a HTML table

```
  var AuditHTML = "<table class='tablesorter full_width_table info_table_style ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive' id='auditTable'>" +
                    "<thead >" +
                       "<tr class='ui-bar-b schedule_row '>" +
                         "<th>ID</th>" +
                         "<th>User ID</th>" +
                         "<th>Action</th>" +
                         "<th>Date</th>" +
                         "<th>App ID</th>" +
                         "<th>Device ID</th>" +
                         "<th>Notes</th>" +
                       "</tr>" +
                     "</thead>" +
                     "<tbody>";


        for (s = 0; s < auditList.length; s++) {
            if (auditList[s].Date <= loggingto && auditList[s].Date >= loggingfrom) {
                AuditHTML += "<tr class='schedule_row display' id='auditTr_" + s + "'>" +
                          "<td> " + auditList[s].ID + "</td>" +
                          "<td> " + auditList[s].UserID + "</td>" +
                          "<td> " + auditList[s].Action + "</td>" +
                          "<td> " + auditList[s].Date + "</td>" +
                          "<td> " + auditList[s].AppID + "</td>" +
                          "<td> " + auditList[s].DeviceID + "</td>" +
                          "<td class='note'> " + auditList[s].Notes + "</td>";
                AuditHTML += "</tr>";
            }
        }
       AuditHTML += "</tbody></table>";

       $("#auditContent").html(AuditHTML);
```

HTML - to display table

```
 <div id="auditContent">
        </div>
```

Thanks for your time/help!

Comment: Jeezes, that's milliseconds from epoch, and all you do is `new Date(1404860400000)` to get a javascript date

Comment: create a javascript function like function parseJsonDate(jsonDateString) {
                return new Date(parseInt(jsonDateString.replace('/Date(', '')));
            } and call it where you assigning date.

Comment: When creating a function like that and passing the json dates to it, they all show as Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself using JQuery moment:

Created a method to run each JSON date through:

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDateString) {
    return moment(jsonDateString).format("D-MMM-YY").toUpperCase();
}
```

And called it when rendering the table:

```
"<td> " + parseJsonDate(auditList[s].Date) + "</td>" +
```

Comment: what is moment in here?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the JavaScript date object. You can pass a date in milliseconds into its constructor.

```
var d = new Date(1404860400000);
```

You could then call the various get methods to return the date in the format you want.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp